# Error 503 after a file_get_html to Amazon OfferListing link

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

currently i'm doing and integration between Amazon and my website through the API.
But now i'm facing a problem, The Api doesn't return information about the shipping cost and there are many items with higly price on the shipping cost.
So I thought grab the data directly from the amazon site through the simple html dom.
First I try on any product view to test it and grab the price and I did it.
But when i try to make a simple_html_dom to a link like the next one
http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00E45043A/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new
(This kind of links show me a table with the shipping information) 
I got and error like this:
2014-03-04T05:48:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00E45043A/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
  in /var/www/mysite/lib/phpseclib/simpleDom/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

The request is failing here:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

Anyhelp would be appreciate it.

Comment: In Amazon, the site details are coming from JSON. That may block you to get the data. Check how the data comes. That may help you. I have also gone through same problem.

Comment: Thanks!, but i cant find any XHR request about the shipping information. I tried with CURL to the same url a few minutes ago, and i got a 500 error.
Maybe Amazon is blocking the access to the offerListing details. Do you know another way to get the right shipping information?
Thanks

Comment: I think cURL is not going to help you on this.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed it too. :P, the question is, Why I can get info trhough the simple_dom_html in the producto view, and why not in the product offers linting details?

Comment: I have found that the required details load only after the page fully loaded.

Comment: It's because file_get_contents doesn't send proper headers.

Comment: @BetoCastillo We need to find the details which are loading after full page load. To get it, we must get the json which is having a array of values. In that array, we need to parse it and get what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this error because the size of the html exceeds the simple_html_dom.php MAX_FILE_SIZE constant which is by default 600000.
Edit simple_html_dom.php and change MAX_FILE_SIZE to something bigger.
You can find it at line 66 if it's the stock parser:
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
For me, that solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks you saved my time, Kindly explain more about this size. I put there 6000000. It will cause for anything in my project?